# HttpWebRequest returning error "The underlying connection was closed"

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, system.net.httpwebrequest

I simply need to call a web page and get the response page back.  I use the following code to call the webpage.  This code has been working great for months.  However, just recently, the line that calls GetResponse is now returning the error "The underlying connection was closed".  I have attached the Verbose logs of the System.Net but I cannot figure out what is wrong.  If I change the URL to http://microsoft.com then the response works just fine.  It seems to be related to the specific site I am calling.  I have tried many different url calls to gocomics.com  (like https, no www, etc.) but nothing has been successful.  When I look at the logs, I cannot determine why the GetResponse is failing.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://www.gocomics.com"));

// Set some reasonable limits on resources used by this request
request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 4;
request.MaximumResponseHeadersLength = 4;

// Set credentials to use for this request.
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

I have also tried just using this simple code but still not success

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://www.gocomics.com"));
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Here is the System.Net logging set at Verbose

```
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [51100] Entering 

WebRequest::Create(http://www.gocomics.com/)
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [51100] Entering HttpWebRequest#54986669::HttpWebRequest(http://www.gocomics.com/#1880366986)
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] Current OS installation type is 'Client'.
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] RAS supported: True
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [51100] Exiting HttpWebRequest#54986669::HttpWebRequest()
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [51100] Exiting WebRequest::Create()    -> HttpWebRequest#54986669
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [51100] Entering HttpWebRequest#54986669::GetResponse()
System.Net Error: 0 : [51100] Can't retrieve proxy settings for Uri 'http://www.gocomics.com/'. Error code: 12180.
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [51100] Entering ServicePoint#23686174::ServicePoint(www.gocomics.com:80)
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] Associating HttpWebRequest#54986669 with ServicePoint#23686174
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] Associating Connection#31609076 with HttpWebRequest#54986669
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] Connection#31609076 - Created connection from 10.0.0.208:13441 to 66.6.101.183:80.
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] Associating HttpWebRequest#54986669 with ConnectStream#20903718
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] HttpWebRequest#54986669 - Request: GET / HTTP/1.1

System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] ConnectStream#20903718 - Sending headers
{
Host: www.gocomics.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
}.
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] Connection#31609076 - Received status line: Version=1.1, StatusCode=301, StatusDescription=Moved Permanently.
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] Connection#31609076 - Received headers
{
Connection: Close
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html
Location: https://www.gocomics.com/
}.
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] ConnectStream#51746094::ConnectStream(Buffered 0 bytes.)
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] Associating HttpWebRequest#54986669 with ConnectStream#51746094
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] Associating HttpWebRequest#54986669 with HttpWebResponse#41215084
System.Net Warning: 0 : [51100] HttpWebRequest#54986669::() - Error code 301 was received from server response.
System.Net Warning: 0 : [51100] HttpWebRequest#54986669::() - Resubmitting request.
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [51100] Entering ServicePoint#12096874::ServicePoint(www.gocomics.com:443)
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] Associating HttpWebRequest#54986669 with ServicePoint#12096874
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] Associating Connection#26209817 with HttpWebRequest#54986669
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] Connection#26209817 - Created connection from 10.0.0.208:13443 to 66.6.101.183:443.
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] TlsStream#860689::.ctor(host=www.gocomics.com, #certs=0, checkCertificateRevocationList=False, sslProtocols=Default)
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] Associating HttpWebRequest#54986669 with ConnectStream#35288276
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] HttpWebRequest#54986669 - Request: GET / HTTP/1.1

System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] ConnectStream#35288276 - Sending headers
{
Host: www.gocomics.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
}.
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] SecureChannel#37533195::.ctor(hostname=www.gocomics.com, #clientCertificates=0, encryptionPolicy=RequireEncryption)
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] Enumerating security packages:
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100]     Negotiate
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100]     NegoExtender
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100]     Kerberos
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100]     NTLM
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100]     TSSSP
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100]     pku2u
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100]     WDigest
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100]     Schannel
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100]     Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100]     Default TLS SSP
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100]     CREDSSP
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] SecureChannel#37533195 - Left with 0 client certificates to choose from.
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] SecureChannel#37533195::.AcquireClientCredentials, new SecureCredential() (flags=(ValidateManual, NoDefaultCred, SendAuxRecord), m_ProtocolFlags=(Ssl3Client, Tls10Client), m_EncryptionPolicy=RequireEncryption)
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] AcquireCredentialsHandle(package = Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider, intent  = Outbound, scc     = System.Net.SecureCredential)
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = (null), targetName = www.gocomics.com, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffer length=0, Out-Buffer length=120, returned code=ContinueNeeded).
System.Net Error: 0 : [51100] Exception in HttpWebRequest#54986669:: - The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send..
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] Associating HttpWebRequest#54986669 with ServicePoint#12096874
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] Associating Connection#62465990 with HttpWebRequest#54986669
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] Connection#62465990 - Created connection from 10.0.0.208:13444 to 66.6.101.183:443.
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] TlsStream#10968766::.ctor(host=www.gocomics.com, #certs=0, checkCertificateRevocationList=False, sslProtocols=Default)
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] Associating HttpWebRequest#54986669 with ConnectStream#47066262
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] HttpWebRequest#54986669 - Request: GET / HTTP/1.1

System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] ConnectStream#47066262 - Sending headers
{
Host: www.gocomics.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
}.
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] SecureChannel#50668565::.ctor(hostname=www.gocomics.com, #clientCertificates=0, encryptionPolicy=RequireEncryption)
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] SecureChannel#50668565 - Left with 0 client certificates to choose from.
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] Using the cached credential handle.
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = (null), targetName = www.gocomics.com, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
System.Net Information: 0 : [51100] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffer length=0, Out-Buffer length=120, returned code=ContinueNeeded).
System.Net Error: 0 : [51100] Exception in HttpWebRequest#54986669:: - The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send..
System.Net Error: 0 : [51100] Exception in HttpWebRequest#54986669::GetResponse - The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send..
```

Comment: _This code has been working great for months. However, just recently, the line that calls GetResponse is now returning the error "The underlying connection was closed"._ - maybe they've started rejecting calls for some reason. Have you tried setting [the user agent string on the request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.useragent?view=netframework-4.7.2) to one of the popular browsers? Does using a proxy like Fiddler get you any more information?

Answer (score 1):

The site is redirecting to HTTPS, and you explicitly set `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`.  Perhaps the site does not support that protocol version and is closing the connection.

Comment: I tried without using the SecurityProtocol as well as changing the URL but the same error is happening.

Comment: It looks like the site only supports TLS 1.2, so I believe you are correct that the security protocol version is likely not the issue.

Comment: Do you need to send credentials to the site?  If not, you may try leaving the property as null.  For example, `request.Credentials = null;`

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following to your registry will enforce TLS1.2

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
>   "SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
>   "SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

The HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE[Wow6432Node]Microsoft.NETFramework\: SchUseStrongCrypto registry key has a value of type DWORD. A value of 1 causes your app to use strong cryptography. The strong cryptography uses more secure network protocols (TLS 1.2, TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.0) and blocks protocols that are not secure. A value of 0 disables strong cryptography.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#schusestrongcrypto

Answer (score 0):

Following might the solutions -

1. You can try to use different or multiple SecurityProtocols :

> SecurityProtocolTypes: SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3,
>   SecurityProtocolType.Tls, SecurityProtocolType.Tls11

2. As this code was working before, it might be the issue on server side as well where they have disabled support for TLS1.0
3. Set `HttpWebRequest.KeepAlive` to `False`